# An extra edit mode button for convenience of scrolled content?

Tags: usability, modal-view

Any concerns with 2 Edit Mode buttons that switch the entire view to edit mode? Second is just for convenience if scrolled.

The Edit button is required as visual elements appear in this modal view that are not in the View Mode.

Example:

```
  Show details/Edit
```

Content Content Content

Content Content Content

Content Content Content

Content Content Content

Content Content Content

Content Content Content

```
  Show details/Edit
```

Content Content Content

Content Content Content

Content Content Content

Again, the same modal view is called upon when selecting either - whole view changes. The idea is to not make the user scroll back up when they decide they need to edit something.

Thoughts?  Yes I know in-line editing might be better. The concern is that we need to show a published version of the report and one that shows all of the behind the scenes if you have access, and to allow you to make changes- thus the view-modes approach.

Thank you in advance for your thoughts. Getting a lot of pressure by a coder (less designer) to go with a top of the page approach because it affects the whole view. I'm about convenience over tradition.

Set me straight.

Answer (score 1):

I presumed both edit buttons point to the same page. Coincidentally [NNgroup published an article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/duplicate-links/) on something similar.

At a glance without reading your description, I thought the edit buttons are used to modify their own section content. There is nothing wrong with your approach but I think it make better sense to allow the edit button to change its own respective content. Meaning the first edit button should not make changes to the content under the 2nd edit button.

Otherwise you might want to unify the edit buttons into a single button and placed it somewhere visible/accessible. If you have the luxury of time, you could explore using sticky bar.

#### Sticky Header Solution

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbpEQo.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

#### Go to the Top Solution

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ27XM.png)</sup>